# cisco anyconnect strange behavior on disconnection

Tags: linux, vpn, dns, fedora, cisco-anyconnect

i have two fedora boxes, one is a fresh fedora 36 install and the other is an upgraded fedora 36 from fedora 35.

the new and fresh one i've installed cisco-anyconnect-vpn-4.10.05095-1.x86_64.rpm client and everything works as expected.

the older machine i've experimented with several distinct anyconnect version (4.6, 4.9 and 4.10 most recently) and it works, however every time i disconnect from vpn it refuses to properly restore dns settings.

[image]

on the left the new machine, behaves well when disconnect, on the right the old, upgraded one, doesn't restores proper dns configuration on disconnect.

anyone ever faced dns issues on disconnect from anyconnect?

any clue is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after some trial and error jazz, i figured out this:

```
[sombriks@ignis ~]$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf 
# (several lines of comments)     
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.
[Resolve]
# (more comments)
DNS=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 8.8.4.4
# (more commented properties)
```

for some reason set this DNS property made connect/disconnect works properly on both machines.

not sure why it works, but it works nicely.

so try it if you too have issues with official cisco anyconnect client.