# Can't access internet after disconnecting AnyConnect VPN on Fedora

Tags: vpn, fedora, cisco-vpn-client

I am using Fedora 38 KDE and Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 4.10. After disconnecting from the VPN, I cannot access to any internet site.

Before connecting to the VPN, I have the following configuration:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
  Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
...

$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

When I connect to the VPN, `/etc/resolv.conf` changes to

```
domain <vpn domain>
nameserver <ip>
nameserver <ip>
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search <vpn domain> .
```

and

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
  Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: <ip>
  DNS Servers: <ip> <ip>
  DNS Domain: <vpn domain> ~.
```

After disconnecting from the VPN, the /etc/resolv.conf file is changed back. But `systemd-resolve --status` shows the same result as when the VPN is connected.
After running `systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` everything works fine and `systemd-resolve --status` shows the original result.
Everything works fine on Ubuntu 22.04 with same Cisco AnyConnect version.

Comment: Set Any Connect up to run as Split Tunnel

Comment: @John Where can I set this setting?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1735049/8672) can help.

Comment: @harrymc I tried to specify dns in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf , but after that I can't open sites inside the corporate network with vpn enabled

Comment: The DNS servers in the answer are universal ones, they should work equally well in both, Strange.

Comment: Please see this:    https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/119006-configure-anyconnect-00.html